# Unable to log in after creating a user

Tags: useradd, passwd

I have an install script that creates a user:

```
sudo useradd -c "My test user" -G users -m -p "passw0rd$" -K PASS_MAX_DAYS=-1 -s /bin/bash myuser
```

However when I try to log in via ssh I get the following error:

```
myuser@myserver's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

But when I login as root and update the password to the same one specified in the original command:

```
passwd passw0rd$
```

I am then able to log in without any problem. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Are you encrypting the password, as described in the useradd man page?

Comment: I am just typing the commands above, so I don't think so

Comment: try using a password that doesn't contain a dollar sign, see if that works

Comment: No that didn't work